# Eclipse project does not want to clean

Tags: android, eclipse-3.6

I have been working on eclipse helios, trying to SVN repository project. Safe to say it checked out correctly to a specific work-space.

however when I copy the file from the eclipse packaged folder into the root folder and restarting the eclipse.

The clean project function becomes inactive, which brings about a lot of errors such as the:

> An internal error occurred during: `"Launching
>   iReadTrunk".java.lang.NullPointerException`,

when I try running the app. Please! Help.

Comment: Firstly, Eclipse Helios is really deprecated by now, I'd suggest to use a newer version. Secondly, there might be some invisible config files in your project which the compiler does not recognize (they are created by svn automatically). Right-click your project - Properties - Resources - Resource filters - add - exlude all - files and folders - name matches .svn

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Eclipse Juno, Helios is very old.  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/juno/sr1